# Can not Connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to connect Mac with Visual Studio 2015 that visual studio was unable to connect to the mac.

I followed this ,
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

The problem is that connected icon not showing. That is the Mac not connected. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Please check if there are some details in the Output window when selecting Xamarin from the *Show output from:* combo box. There are plenty reasons why it is not connecting, e.g. incompatible version of Xamarin Studio on your Mac.

Comment: Checked the Xamarin Output window in the Visual Studio, the reason for me was this: `The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 9.6) on the Mac (ip address here) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS 9.8.`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

1. Check the network between Mac and PC.
2. Check that you are using the latest version Xamarin for Mac and Pc. It is important. I got a stable connection only version 4.2.0.68(before this version was a pain).
3. Try several restarts Mac and PC(sometimes it helps).

If this does not work - read this [manual](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's does not working :(